# How to estimate the covariance of an index with a basket of stocks?

Tags: equities, statistics, correlation, covariance

What would be an ideal way to estimate the covariance of an index with a basket of stocks? For example, should I use one-tail ANOVA test or an individual stock & index F-test?

Comment: Is your comparison vs. the basket of 15 stocks as a whole or vs. each of the 15 individual stocks (the trivial case)?

Comment: Look at the bilinearity property of the covariance function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are referring to measuring correlation and/or cointegration.  May I suggest you take a look at [another question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1027/1407) with several answers. I believe it may include an answer to yours as well...